# How can I change configuration property for Neo4j Java driver?

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, neo4j

I am doing a homework assigment about Neo4j. I am using Neo4j Java driver library with Scala. I made a query to load data from CSV but error appears:

```
configuration property 'dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls' is false
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.util.Futures.blockingGet(Futures.java:111)
```

Is there a way to change this property in IntelliJ?
Thank you!

I tries to google the problem, but it didn't found any answers.

Comment: Isn't that a configuration of the neo4j server? If so, it's not something you can choose in your client code.

Comment: I am not sure. I believe it is default configuration for a library and maybe there is a way to change it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is the property of the neo4j database. You can't update it via IntelliJ. You have to manually update it in the neo4j.conf file. https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/neo4j-conf/

Answer (score 0):

This property is not managed by Neo4j Java Driver, it is managed by Neo4j server.

It is documented here: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/configuration-settings/

Depending on how Neo4j server is deployed, there are multiple ways of updating it. For instance:

1. Binary: add `dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true` to `<neo4j-home>/conf/neo4j.conf` OR ensure it is not set there as it should be `true` by default
2. Docker: set environment variable `NEO4J_dbms_security_allow__csv__import__from__file__urls=true` (more details here: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/docker/configuration/)
3. Neo4j Desktop: edit settings of the target DBMS
4. Neo4j Aura: CSV file should be loaded as a remote file. This error can be reproduced when query references a local file. See the documentation for more details: https://neo4j.com/docs/aura/auradb/importing/importing-data/